# Simple converting java.util.Calendar to Android Time

Tags: android, time, calendar

I'm creating a android.text.format.Time Object from a java.util.Calendar Instance,
and I read it out field by field. Isn't there a more elegant way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's easy - perhaps this may be interesting to someone:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Time t = new Time();
t.set(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("calendar.getTimeInMillis()="+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("t="+t.toMillis(true));
```